# Add tag for "Diggles, the Myth of Fenris"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I asked [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15752/issues-with-running-diggles-the-myth-of-fenris-wiggles-on-windows-7) about the game *Wiggles* from a German developer, forgetting that it was released in English as *[Diggles, the Myth of Fenris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diggles,_the_Myth_of_Fenris)*. Someone kindly created a tag for it. However, I have edited the question to mention the correct name, and think that `diggles` should be the tag for it, with `wiggles` as a tag synonym.

Comment: I edited the tag, but it seems as though I need 5 rep in diggles questions to make a tag synonym...

Answer (score 3):

`<Insert picture of fire-breathing rage turtle and/or other symbology for the purposes of indicating that the job has been successfully completed and a post is being provided so as to indicate this fact and banish a status-completed post from henceforth returning to the front page under traditionally traditional circumstancial circumstances>`

Comment: The job is not *really* completed: Now there is *no* tag for the game anymore.